# Android - An AsyncTask to fill a form

Tags: android, forms, android-asynctask

I have a form with 9 fields. When opening an item I'm calling an AsyncTask in order to retrieve the info from the DB and now I'm thinking what to do in order to use the info for filling the from itself. Apart from that I have a global AsyncTask that I use for several operations between the client and server/DB. * The reason I have a global AsyncTask is that I have a lot of small client->DB interactions with the same mechanism so I re-use the same code.

Option 1: implement a specific scenario in that AsyncTask, send it additional 9 objects and process it: I admit that I don't like this idea, and what if tomorrow I will have a form with more than 9 fields?

Option 2: Creating a dedicated AsyncTask inside the same class/window so I could use the objects inside the AsyncTask. This is a better option unless there is a better one, hence my question. Also see my * comment above. I lose the code re-use.

Options 3: Use a class that is structured like the window (I have it anyway) and fill it as part of the AsyncTask processing but I don't know how to take the info from the class's instance, back to the form.

Option 4: This is where you come into play :) any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full example to post, but I've used a task pattern in the past.

First, you create a little place-holder you can pass around to your `AsyncTask` -- you want to make sure that you separate the UI activity from the background activity; here it's 'execute()`for the background, and`deliverResult()`for the UI thread. I use a`WeakReference` to avoid resource leaks, especially if the activity is refreshed.

```
abstract class Task {
    abstract boolean execute();
    abstract void deliverResult();
}

class QueryTask extends Task {
    private WeakReference<TextView> mView;
    private String mQuery;
    private int mResult;

    public QueryTask( String query, TextView view ) {
        mView = new WeakReference<TextView>( view );
        mQuery = query;
    }

    public boolean execute() {
        // run query
        mResult = query-result;
        return true;
    }

    void deliverResult() {
        TextView view = mView.get();
        if( view != null )
            view.setText( String.valueOf( mResult ) );
    }
```

Next, you create an `AsyncTask` to work a task-list. Here you can use `onProgressUpdate()` to update the UI on the UI thread:

```
class TaskWorker extends AsyncTask<Task, Task, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Task... params) {
        for( int i=0; i<params.length; i++ ) {
            Task task = params[i];
            if( task.execute() )
                publishProgress( task );
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Task... values) {
        for( int i=0; i<value.length; i++ ) {
            values[i].deliveryResult();
        }
    }

}
```

All of this can live inside a class which you can access/reuse anywhere in the code. Say you put it in the class `Tasks`, you would then execute it:

```
Tasks.TaskWorker worker = new Tasks.TaskWorker();

worker.execute( 
    new Tasks.QueryTask( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEES", tvEmpCount ),
    new Tasks.QueryTask( "SELECT SUM(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEES", tvTotalSalary ),
    new Tasks.DownloadTask( "http://avatar.jpg", imgEmp ) );
```

This would then execute one query at a time, populate the UI, and finally download an image (if DownloadTask was implemented).

Comment: I understand your solution is option 2 above? I know how to implement it but I was wondering if there is a cleaner more standardize way to do this. Also, I don't have only TextVIews, I have also Switch and other components on the layout so...

Comment: You can extend the `Task` class to handle any views and queries and results you like. It only handles the connection between the background worker (execute) and the presentation (deliverResults). And this AsyncTask can live in a separate class, along with its various Tasks.

Comment: My asynctask retrieves field=value in json format and each json field is a value for a field on the screen and each field is different (textView, EditText, Switch and so on)...

Comment: How long do those queries run? You might not need an AsyncTask after all.

Comment: I have to because it's a network process and a network process must run in separate thread or else I would get an error about it. I guess using a dedicated asynctask in the same file of the calling class and losing the "code re-use" (Option 2) is a better option

Comment: The pattern above will work well for you, then. I don't think you need to lose code re-use if you follow the pattern.